# RxJS 5 merge operator doesn't work for observables created from array

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

This code logs different result for RxJS 4 and RxJS 5

`Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4]),
  Rx.Observable.from([5,6,7])
).subscribe(i => console.log(i))`

Result for RxJS 4: 1,5,2,6,3,7,4 - the result is correct according to the docs of merge:

> Creates an output Observable which **concurrently** emits all values
>   from every given input Observable

RxJS5: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 - result is the same as from concat operator that is not as described in docs

So how to get the values from two array observables concurrently in RxJS5?

Comment: You are passing synchronous observables. For an explanation of what's happening, see: https://staltz.com/primer-on-rxjs-schedulers.html

Comment: And for the v4 and v5 scheduling differences see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#default-scheduling-changed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant).

The proper solution in RxJS 5:

`Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4], Rx.Scheduler.asap),
  Rx.Observable.from([5,6,7], Rx.Scheduler.asap)
).subscribe(i => console.log(i))`